# PGI FORTRAN90 allocating an array passed to a subroutine (seg fault)

Tags: arrays, fortran, fortran90, allocation, pgi

Here is some fortran90 code that I'm compiling using the PGI fortran compiler. I can't seem to allocate the array within the subroutine `arraySub()` without seg faulting. It also seg faults if I even check if the array is allocated like this: `allocated(theArray)`. I'm compiling the code on the command line like this: `pgf90 -o test.exe test.f90`

```
program test
implicit none
real,dimension(:,:),allocatable :: array

write(*,*) allocated(array) ! Should be and is false
call arraySub(array)

end program


subroutine arraySub(theArray)
implicit none
real,dimension(:,:),allocatable,intent(inout) :: theArray

write(*,*) 'Inside arraySub()'
allocate(theArray(3,2)) ! Seg fault happens here
write(*,*) allocated(theArray)

end subroutine
```

I'm confused as to why `theArray` is not allocatable inside the `arraySub` subroutine since I'm initializing it with `intent(inout)` and `allocatable`. Especially strange is that `allocated(theArray)` also seg faults. I was wondering if someone could point me in the right direction to a solution. Thanks in advance!

Edit: Since there isn't actual example code in the duplicate question, I'll post a solution using a module:

```
module arrayMod   
  real,dimension(:,:),allocatable :: theArray    
end module arrayMod

program test
   use arrayMod
   implicit none

   interface
      subroutine arraySub
      end subroutine arraySub
   end interface

   write(*,*) allocated(theArray)
   call arraySub
   write(*,*) allocated(theArray) 
end program test

subroutine arraySub
   use arrayMod

   write(*,*) 'Inside arraySub()'
   allocate(theArray(3,2))
end subroutine arraySub
```

Comment: You've misunderstood the advice offered in the answer to the duplicate.  Put the subroutine into a module and let the compiler create the interface for you.  If I have time later I'll find an example hereabouts for your education.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark I'm interested in seeing an example, if you have time at some point. Thanks!